# Changing three.js background to transparent or other color

Tags: css, html, canvas, html5-canvas, three.js

I've been trying to change what seems to be the default background color of my canvas from black to transparent / any other color - but no luck.

My HTML:

```
<canvas id="canvasColor">
```

My CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
#canvasColor {
 z-index: 998;
opacity:1;
background: red;
}
</style>
```

As you can see in the following online example I have some animation appended to the canvas, so cant just do a opacity: 0; on the id.

Live preview:
http://devsgs.com/preview/test/particle/

Any ideas how to overwrite the default black?

Comment: At the beginning of `function init() {`, your canvas is red! Three.js changes it to black with `setClearColorHex`!

Comment: Related: [Transparent background with three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495302/transparent-background-with-three-js)

Answer (score 332, accepted):

I came across this when I started using three.js as well. It's actually a javascript issue. You currently have:

```js
// in your three.js init function
renderer.setClearColorHex( 0x000000, 1 );

// => change it to
renderer.setClearColorHex( 0xffffff, 1 );
```

**Update:** Thanks to HdN8 for the updated solution:

```js
renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff, 0);
```

**Update #2:** As pointed out by WestLangley in [another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495302/transparent-background-with-three-js) - you must now use the below code when creating a new WebGLRenderer instance in conjunction with the `setClearColor()` function:

```js
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });
```

**Update #3:** Mr.doob points out that since [`r78`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/releases/tag/r78) you can alternatively use the code below to set your scene's background colour:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene(); // initialising the scene
scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xff0000 );
```

Comment: You are indeed right. The canvas is indeed transparent pr. default, so shame on me. Thanks a lot for pointing out where to change this - it looks great now!

Comment: Nice, this bugged me for a bit too.  I found in the three.js script this method is soon deprecated, use setClearColor( 0xffffff, 1) instead.

Comment: @HdN8 - thanks for update, I've added it to the answer.

Comment: setClearColor( 0xffffff, 1) did not work for me (made it white) but setClearColor( 0xffffff, 0) did work (made it transparent)

Comment: Thanks Ronen - the original question was about changing the background to any colour but, like you, most people coming here probably want to make it transparent. I've updated the code so that the background colour's opacity is 0.

Comment: Since `r78` you can simply do `scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xff0000 );`

Comment: Year 2020: `scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xff0000 );` worked.

Answer (score 31):

A full answer: (Tested with r71)

To set a background color use:

```js
renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff ); // white background - replace ffffff with any hex color
```

If you want a transparent background you will have to enable alpha in your renderer first:

```js
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: true } ); // init like this
renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff, 0 ); // second param is opacity, 0 => transparent
```

[View the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/renderers/WebGLRenderer.setClearColor) for more info.

Answer (score 23):

For transparency, this is also mandatory: `renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: true } )` via [Transparent background with three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495302/transparent-background-with-three-js)

Answer (score 10):

In 2020, using r115, it works very well with this:

```js
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = null;
```

Answer (score 3):

I found that when I created a scene via the three.js editor, I not only had to use the correct answer's code (above), to set up the renderer with an alpha value and the clear color, I had to go into the app.json file and find the "Scene" Object's "background" attribute and set it to:
`"background: null"`.

The export from Three.js editor had it originally set to "background": 0

Answer (score 1):

Set renderer clear colour
With the below code
 `renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 1 );`

Answer (score -1):

I'd also like to add that if using the three.js editor don't forget to set the background colour to clear as well in the index.html.

```
background-color:#00000000
```