# About threejs transparent background

Tags: three.js

[image]

[image]

Mobile phone display
PC is opaque

Comment: Can you show your code? How are you instantiating the renderer? What is the clearColor? What is your mobile device? What is your PC? Which one is not working properly?

Comment: renderer.alpha =true

Comment: @zhubenjie this is not the expected code. And your question, in general, is for people with paranormal abilities, like telepaths or mediums.

Comment: How to write。。 。。。。

Comment: @zhubenjie http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495302/transparent-background-with-three-js/20496296#20496296

Comment: thanks~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this example:

```
  renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
   /* renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);*/

        renderer.setSize(300, 300);
    /*renderer.setClearColor( 0xa9db8b );*/
```

https://jsfiddle.net/VsWb9/5847/