# Transparency in three.js scene.background texture

Tags: three.js

I could not change it, even with opacity in video css tag.
Thanks for possible answer.
José Roberto Lazzareschi

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495302/transparent-background-with-three-js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transparent background with three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495302/transparent-background-with-three-js)

Answer (score 0):

The suggestions did not helped me.
I´ve changed the opacity of the movie in Movavi and solved my desire.

```
...var videobg=document.getElementById('video');
...var texturebg=new THREE.VideoTexture(videobg);
...scene.background=texturebg;
```

Thank You for the attention.
José Roberto