# How to make transparent background in three.js canvas?

Tags: javascript, css, three.js

I am trying to use wave particle animation from codepen - https://codepen.io/kevinsturf/pen/ExLdPZ but that has white background. When I set red background to body, it is not shown as soon as canvas is rendered.

I also tried to set alpha to 0 i.e.

```
    renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff, 0);
```

How can I make it transparent?

Comment: For `WebGLRenderer`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20496296/1461008.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transparent background with three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495302/transparent-background-with-three-js)

Comment: In the codepen link that I shared, it is using CanvasRenderer. I have checked all the StackOverflow answers & did some more other research before asking here.
I don't know to convert it to WebGLRenderer either, so here I am asking for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to pass `alpha` as `true` to the `renderer`:

```
renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer({ alpha: true });
```

Then you can set it to transparent:

```
renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 );
```

Also added a black background color to the `div` so we can see it working

```css
.waves { 
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black
}
```

```js
/* 

ThreeJs custom waves
Original script by ThreeJS : https://threejs.org/examples/canvas_particles_waves.html
Modified version for Cloudoru by Kevin Rajaram : http://kevinrajaram.com
Date: 08/14/2014


*/

var SEPARATION = 40, AMOUNTX = 130, AMOUNTY = 35;

var container;
var camera, scene, renderer;
/*

if (window.WebGLRenderingContext){
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true, antialias: true });
    }
else {
    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
    }
*/

var particles, particle, count = 0;

var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    container = document.createElement( 'div' );
    document.body.appendChild( container );
    if(container) {
        container.className += container.className ? ' waves' : 'waves';
    }

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 120, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
    camera.position.y = 150; //changes how far back you can see i.e the particles towards horizon
    camera.position.z = 300; //This is how close or far the particles are seen
    
    camera.rotation.x = 0.35;
    
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    particles = new Array();

    var PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
    var material = new THREE.SpriteCanvasMaterial( {

        color: 0xFFFFFF, //changes color of particles
        program: function ( context ) {

            context.beginPath();
            context.arc( 0, 0, 0.1, 0, PI2, true );
            context.fill();

        }

    } );

    var i = 0;

    for ( var ix = 0; ix < AMOUNTX; ix ++ ) {

        for ( var iy = 0; iy < AMOUNTY; iy ++ ) {

            particle = particles[ i ++ ] = new THREE.Sprite( material );
            particle.position.x = ix * SEPARATION - ( ( AMOUNTX * SEPARATION ) / 2 );
            particle.position.z = iy * SEPARATION - ( ( AMOUNTY * SEPARATION ) - 10 );
            scene.add( particle );

        }

    }

    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer({ alpha: true });
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    
  renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 );
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

}

function onWindowResize() {

    windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
    windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    render();

}

function render() {

    var i = 0;

    for ( var ix = 0; ix < AMOUNTX; ix ++ ) {

        for ( var iy = 0; iy < AMOUNTY; iy ++ ) {

            particle = particles[ i++ ];
            particle.position.y = ( Math.sin( ( ix + count ) * 0.5 ) * 20 ) + ( Math.sin( ( iy + count ) * 0.5 ) * 20 );
            particle.scale.x = particle.scale.y = ( Math.sin( ( ix + count ) * 0.3 ) + 2 ) * 4 + ( Math.sin( ( iy + count ) * 0.5 ) + 1 ) * 4;

        }

    }

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

    // This increases or decreases speed
    count += 0.2;

}
```

```css
canvas{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:2;
}

.waves { 
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r68/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I have tried passing the alpha argument also before but that didn't work. Maybe I missed something earlier. I guess I didn't pass alpha inside curly braces { }.