# Threejs canvas background black

Tags: javascript, three.js

I made a trial with basic scene of threejs but I can't understand why the canvas background is completely black.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My first Three.js app</title>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; }
        canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%;background-color: white; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="Stereos/threejs/three.js"></script>
    <script>
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**

Code at felpone.netsons.org

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The color of the background of the canvas is not determined by the CSS value but using `renderer.setClearColor (0xff0000, 1);`

Comment: That is not quite true. Use `renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: true } ); renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 );` and the CSS background color will show through.

Comment: @WestLangley actually the confusion (and mine too) comes from the fact that the canvas background color behaves differently based on where it is defined; as a css style on the canvas element directly (http://jsfiddle.net/dzdoLosm/) or as a css element by itself (http://jsfiddle.net/n0jdpr76/) where setting the `setClearColor( color, 0 )` does not seem to work.

Comment: Your clearColor has zero alpha. Try `renderer.setClearColor( 0xff0000, 0.5 );`

Comment: @WestLangley I assume you are talking about the second fiddle. Yes it is zero because I want the green color of the canvas style to show through. Setting it to 0.5 would only make the red color of the renderer background color to show up.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on the latest build of Three.JS.

Comment: @TylerChong check https://stackoverflow.com/a/16177178/14677302. Just to note - this doesn't work for when you are using UnrealBloom effect. Does anyone know how I can make the background transparent even when using bloom?

Answer (score 7):

You can control the background color using css, but you must first set the "alpha" of your WebGLRenderer to "true".

In you example, I added the alpha option and set to true in the renderer, and I also added the background-color property in the body style.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My first Three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; background-color: white; }
            canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: white; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script src="Stereos/threejs/three.js"></script>
    <script>
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {alpha: true} );
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

Better add the background to the scene directly ***which can be a texture or a THREE.Color!***

From r78 versions onwards, you can use the code below to set your scene's background colour:

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x000000 );
```

#### Docs:

- [Scene.background](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/scenes/Scene.background)

Comment: This should be higher in the question stack!

Answer (score 3):

You made a scene, created a camera and created a renderer, but you're missing two important things: adding something to render, and actually rendering it.

After your last line, add

```
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( 
    new THREE.CubeGeometry( 1,1,1 ), 
    new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial() 
);
scene.add( cube );

camera.position.set( 2,2,2 );
camera.lookAt( cube.position );

renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

That will create a cube on the origin ( 0,0,0 ), with size 1 unit; place the camera a bit away from it and pointed at the cube; and then call the renderer to render the cube.

Answer (score 2):

Updating this for the latest version of ThreeJS (2019) -

After you instantiate your scene using:

```
scene = new THREE.Scene();
```

You can then access the "background" property of this object and set the hex color like this:

```
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xf5f5f5);
```

Answer (score 1):

@Jaume Sanchez is the correct answer. Although the others answers are factual, I don't think that they answer what you where asking as a person new to threeJS. the    `var renderer`is just a reference to your render target. your code does not draw anthing. You also do not have a camera in your scene to look at anything. [Creating a scene](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/introduction/Creating-a-scene) a tutorial for getting started

Answer (score 1):

You say that you tried with basic scene. And problem is that you are getting black screen.
I have see you code. And I have found this mistake.

You had not called render method also.

`renderer.render(scene, camera);`

Also you have not added any Geometry (Mesh) to threejs scene. (Basic thing)*

**so you might getting black screen**

after all, you want to change black to white screen.

then set

```
 scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);
```

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason:

```
renderer.setClearColor(0xff0000, 1);
```

does not work, try this:

```
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.domElement.className = "domElement";
```

and in css add a selector:

```
.domElement {
  background-color: red; /* any color */
}
```