# Changing the background in three.js

Tags: three.js

Please may someone tell me how to change the background using Three. Js?
Note that I'm rendering this project with WebGL.

Comment: You can find a discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29422223/1980846

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff, 1);`

See http://jsfiddle.net/L0rdzbej/7/

Three.js r.71

Also this has been asked before: [Changing three.js background to transparent or other color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177056/changing-three-js-background-to-transparent-or-other-color)

Comment: Thanks, but I have another quesion: can you use this code with other rendering platforms, like SVG?