# Three.js canvas background to white or transparent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas, three.js

How to change the canvas black color to white. This is the [code](https://jsfiddle.net/78r60zar/4/). I want to change its color to white or transparent.

I tried suggestions from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177056/changing-three-js-background-to-transparent-or-other-color) but nothing has worked from the suggested answers.

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });

renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff, 0);
```

Can someone help me how to change the color to white or transparent

Comment: The problem with the code you posted to is the sphere that is being added. If you add the code in your post for white background, then remove the line `scene.add(sphereMesh);` you will get a white background.

Comment: i tried this but it is still black

Comment: if i remove this line then i cant see the image

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/78r60zar/2/. See what image? I don't see any image

Comment: jsfiddle is blocking the image due to cross domain

Comment: please check this https://jsfiddle.net/78r60zar/4/

Comment: Check it for what? I see a rotating scene of an abandoned building. What am I meant to be checking?

Comment: by removing scene.add(sphereMesh); i cannot see that building image do you get my point?https://jsfiddle.net/78r60zar/6/

Comment: Why would you need a transparent background if you are covering it with sphere environment anyway? Your transparent background was probably working all along, it was just covered with the sphere environment.

Comment: i want to remove the black background and i want that backgound to be transparent or white.

Comment: ?? But you have the panorama as a background. You cant have a panorama and a transparent background. I really don't understand

Comment: The black color appears before loading the panorama and i simply need to make that black color to white.

Comment: to add on what @2pha already told you, just get your camera farther and you'll see that the background is actually transparent : https://jsfiddle.net/78r60zar/7/

Comment: in this one https://jsfiddle.net/78r60zar/4/ how can i remove the black color?

Comment: that's exactly the one I tweaked... Just set the    `renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff, 0);`and move your camera away from your sphere Mesh.