# Renderer clear color not working : black background instead?

Tags: three.js

A picture being worth a thausand words :

[image]

I would like to have the black background replaced with the fog color (the violet color). Here is some code :

```
var fogColor = 0xeab5ef

//...

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setClearColor(fogColor);
element = renderer.domElement;
container = glFrame;
container.appendChild(element);
effect = new THREE.StereoEffect(renderer);

// ...
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(90, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.001, 800);

// ...
scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2(fogColor, .0029)
```

On the DOM side, every parent of the canvas and itself has `background:transparent`

Any ideas why this happens ?

Comment: Use various methods http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177056/changing-three-js-background-to-transparent-or-other-color maybe depending on version.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `renderer.setClearColor(fogColor,1);`?

it might be black because your alpha value is zero

Comment: I tried it all and finally gave up, pasted the terrain with fog example, then migrated my code to this skeleton and ... bouya! it works. So I don't know what caused the black background, but now it works.