# threejs setClearColor setting the opacity to 0 although the background is not there

Tags: background, three.js

I want to set the background color to blank, using the `renderer.setClearColor (0xff0000, 0)`[setClearColor ]:[Changing three.js background to transparent or other color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177056/changing-three-js-background-to-transparent-or-other-color/16177178#16177178), setting the opacity to 0, although the background is not there, but on the page, there is almost no model

I have added some photo instructions,but the reputation is not enough， please check the link :https://github.com/shunzizhan/threejsDemo/wiki/three-scene

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Please explain in a better way what your problem is and what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @shunzizhan Can you provide a live link here in the comments?

Comment: This problem has been solved，3Q @WestLangley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.renderer = new WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true,
  alpha: true
})
```

Set properties `alpha` true and then

```
this.renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 0)
```

it works