# Is there a way to render a three.js scene over a html video element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js, augmented-reality

I am trying to make an AR app that places North, East, South and West markers through a phone camera. I want to render a scene with a transparent background that overlays a video element of the phone camera.

Renderer code (scene.js):

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene(),
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000),
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });

renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 1 );
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

HTML:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
    </head>

    <body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>

        <video id='video' width='100%' autoplay></video>
        <canvas id='canvas' width='100%' height='100%'></canvas>
        <div id="sliderContainer" class="slidecontainer">
            <input type="range" min="0" max="359" value="1" class="slider" id="myRange">
            <p id="sliderOut">0</p>
        </div>

        <script src="../js/three.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/scene.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/deviceCoords.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/location.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/maths.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/video.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/main.js"></script>


    </body>

    </html>
```

CSS:

```
    body {
        margin: 0;
    }

    canvas {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%
    }

    #sliderContainer {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 20%;
    }

    .slider {
        width: 80%;
    }

    #sliderOut {
        color: chartreuse;
    }

    #video {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: -10;
    }
```

I have tried researching this but everything I've found hasn't seemed to work.
For instance a similar question: [Changing three.js background to transparent or other color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177056/changing-three-js-background-to-transparent-or-other-color/31636198)

I am new to three.js so I may be misunderstanding how it works.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at this [forum post](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/webcam-as-scene-of-fbx-3d-model/4683/5?u=prisoner849)

Comment: Ok, so on the forum Mugen87 (moderator) states that it isn't possible. Perhaps I need to explore alternatives such as AR.js.

Comment: Have you had a look at the question from the Russian segment and the code snippet from its answer (that I've mentioned in that forum thread)?

Comment: My apologies, I didn't see that at first.
I have looked at that three.js example and code before and even used it to create my own version on my project however I would need to re-position the video object for each different screen the app ran on.

Comment: I am just trying to make the background of the scene transparent so I can display a video element beneath.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true, preserveDrawingBuffer:true });

and:

renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 );

?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

Just tried your code and still nothing.

I just get a white background. Editing the page through chrome dev tools shows me that both the video elements and threejs scene are functioning, just the threejs scene isn't transparent.

Comment: OH! One other gotcha that got me recently.. Make sure there is NO background attribute being applied to your canvas. even perhaps explicitly set canvas.style.background="" in startup... let me know if that helps...

Comment: I edited the background element through chrome dev tools while the site was running and there was no change again. Still a white background.

Answer (score 0):

I found what was going wrong.

I had an extra canvas element under the video that was blocking the video from showing underneath the three.js scene.

```
<video id='video' width='100%' autoplay></video>
<!--Canvas element that was blocking scene-->
    <canvas id='canvas' width='100%' height='100%'></canvas>

    <div id="sliderContainer" class="slidecontainer">
        <input type="range" min="0" max="359" value="1" class="slider" id="myRange">
        <p id="sliderOut">0</p>
    </div>
```

The scene is now transparent after removing the extra canvas and I can now view the webcam feed below.