# Classes, Collision detection & for loop problems

Tags: javascript, loops, class, three.js, collision-detection

Im currently using THREE.js to code a simple game of which the Torus is the obstacle and the sphere is the avatar. I did originally just set a var to create the sphere which worked fine, of which I then added key codes although now later on in the progress ive tried embedding it within a class and this error message comes up: [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeKf4.png)

Bellow is my entire code the sphere class is lines 289-382:
-also my "cloud" i want to set in a for loop with they are (obsticalelist4) but they are looping why is this?

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();                      // Create the scene and a camera to view it
//element.style.background-color;

// fogColor = new THREE.Color(0xCCCCCC);                //Create colour of fog

// scene.background = fogColor;
// scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(fogColor, 0.25,30);

// Specify the portion of the scene visiable at any time (in degrees)
//var fieldOfView = 75;


// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177056/changing-three-js-background-to-transparent-or-other-color/31636198

var scene = new THREE.Scene();      // initialising the scene
scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x87cefa ); //adding color to sky 

//var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });


var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.5, 50 );

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;



var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 2 );
directionalLight.position.set( 0, 1, 0 );       //default; light shining from top
directionalLight.castShadow = true;            // default false


var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x404040 );


directionalLight.shadow.camera.top = 10;
directionalLight.shadow.bottom = -10;
directionalLight.shadow.left = -10;
directionalLight.shadow.right = 10;

directionalLight.shadow.mapSize.width = 512;  // default
directionalLight.shadow.mapSize.height = 512; // default
directionalLight.shadow.camera.near = 0.5;    // default
directionalLight.shadow.camera.far = 500;     // default

scene.add( ambientLight, directionalLight );




var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 30, 500 );
var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
var plane = new THREE.Mesh( planeGeometry, planeMaterial );
//var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(0.05, 200, 320, 500);
plane.receiveShadow = true;
scene.add( plane );

 plane.rotation.x = -3.14159 * 4.5/10;
 scene.add(plane);

    plane.position.x = 0;
    plane.position.y = -8;
    plane.position.z = 0; 


    camera.position.z = 15;
    camera.position.y = 0;


renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement ); 


class Entity {
    constructor(x,y,z, rate) {
        this.collidable = true; 
        this.geometry = new THREE.TorusBufferGeometry( 2, 0.5, 10, 100 );
        this.material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {color: 0xffff00} );
        this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh( this.geometry, this.material );

        this.mesh.castShadow = true;
        this.mesh.receiveShadow = true;

        this.mesh.position.x = x
        this.mesh.position.y = y
        this.mesh.position.z = z

        this.originalz = z;
       // this.rate = rate; 
       this.speed = 0.2;


        scene.add(this.mesh);
    }

    update() {  

        this.mesh.position.z += this.speed;//this.rate;  


         if(this.mesh.position.z > 0.5){
            this.mesh.position.z = this.originalz;
            this.speed += 0.015;                        // speeds up torus each refresh of position
        //  }
        }


  }
  Reset(){
    super.reset();
  }
}




  var obstacleList = [];

  var myTorus = new Entity(-10, 1, -160, -1);
  var myTorus1 = new Entity(-5, 1, -30, -1);
  var myTorus2 = new Entity(0, 1, -90, -1);
  var myTorus3 = new Entity(0, 1, -120, -1);
  var myTorus4 = new Entity(10, 1, -60, -1);

obstacleList.push(myTorus1, myTorus2, myTorus3, myTorus4, myTorus );


class Obstacle extends Entity {
    constructor(x,y,z, rate) {
        super();                    // Must call super constructor in derived class before accessing 'this' or returning from derived constructor
        this.collidable = true; 
        this.geometry = new THREE.TorusBufferGeometry( 2, 0.5, 10, 100 );
        this.material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {color: 0xFF0000} );
        this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh( this.geometry, this.material );
        this.mesh.castShadow = true;
      this.mesh.receiveShadow = true;

        this.mesh.position.x = x;
        this.mesh.position.y = y;
        this.mesh.position.z = z;

        this.origionalz = z;// this.rate = rate; 
       this.speed = 0.2;


        scene.add(this.mesh);
    }

    update() {  

        this.mesh.position.z += this.speed;//this.rate;  


         if(this.mesh.position.z > 0.3){        //if torus reaches 0.3 of z axis then return t origional position
            this.mesh.position.z = this.origionalz;
            this.speed += 0.15;                        // speeds up torus each refresh of position

            super.update();

        }


    }
Reset(){
  super.reset();
}
 }

var obstacleList2 = [];
 var Villian = new Obstacle(-10, 1, -160, -1);
  var Villian2 = new Obstacle(-5, 1, -260, -1);
  var Villian3 = new Obstacle(0, 1, -60, -1);
   var Villian4 = new Obstacle(5, 1, -200, -1);
   var Villian5 = new Obstacle(10, 1, -300, -1);
        obstacleList2.push(Villian, Villian2, Villian3, Villian4);



class Service{
    constructor(){

    }
    Update(){

    }
};

function onDocumentKeyDown(event) {
    var keyCode = event.keyCode;
    keyboard.keys[keyCode]=true;
};

function onDocumentKeyUp(event) {
    var keyCode = event.keyCode;
    keyboard.keys[keyCode]=false;
};

class KeyboardService extends Service{
    constructor(){
        super();
        document.addEventListener("keydown", onDocumentKeyDown, false);
        document.addEventListener("keyup", onDocumentKeyUp, false);

        this.keys=[];

    }
    Update(){

    }

    IsKeydown(keyCode){
        return this.keys[keyCode];
    }
};



class Cloud extends Entity { 
    constructor(x,y,z, rate) {
        super();

this.mesh.castShadow = true;
 this.mesh.receiveShadow = true; 

        this.geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 2, 22, 52, -20);
        this.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {color: 0xffffff} );
        this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh( this.geometry, this.material );

        this.mesh.position.x = x
        this.mesh.position.y = y
        this.mesh.position.z = z

scene.add(this.mesh);

}
   update() {  

        this.mesh.position.z += this.speed;//this.rate;  


         if(this.mesh.position.z > 0.3){        //if torus reaches 0.3 of z axis then return t origional position
            this.mesh.position.z = this.origionalz;
            this.speed += 0.015;                        // speeds up torus each refresh of position

            super.update();

        }


    }
Reset(){
  super.reset();
}
 }

var obstacleList3 = [];

var cloud = new Cloud(-20, 10, -10, -1);
var cloud1 = new Cloud(-22, 12, -10, -1);
var cloud2 = new Cloud(-20, 10, -17, -1);
var cloud3 = new Cloud(-22, 12, -19, -1);
var cloud9 = new Cloud(-19, 12, -21, -1);
var cloud4 = new Cloud(18, 10, -10, -1);
var cloud5 = new Cloud(22, 12, -10, -1);
var cloud6 = new Cloud(20, 10, -19, -1);
var cloud7 = new Cloud(22, 12, -21, -1);
var cloud8 = new Cloud(19, 12, -21, -1);
var cloud10 = new Cloud(24, 10, -12, -1);
//var cloud11 = new Cloud(24, 10, -10, -1);
//cloud = new Cloud(-20, 10, -20, -1);
var cloud11 = new Cloud(-22, 12, -20, -1);
var cloud12 = new Cloud(-20, 10, -27, -1);
var cloud13 = new Cloud(-22, 12, -29, -1);
var cloud19 = new Cloud(-19, 12, -31, -1);
var cloud14 = new Cloud(18, 10, -20, -1);
var cloud15 = new Cloud(22, 12, -20, -1);
var cloud16 = new Cloud(20, 10, -29, -1);
var cloud17 = new Cloud(22, 12, -31, -1);
var cloud18 = new Cloud(19, 12, -31, -1);
var cloud20 = new Cloud(24, 10, -22, -1);
 obstacleList3.push(cloud, cloud1, cloud2, cloud3, cloud4, cloud5, cloud6, cloud7, cloud8, cloud9, cloud10, cloud11, cloud12, cloud13, cloud14, cloud15, cloud16, cloud17, cloud18, cloud19, cloud20);




class sphere{ 
  constructor(x,y,z, rate) {

// this.mesh.castShadow = true;
//  this.mesh.receiveShadow = true; 

this.collidable = false; 
var geometry1 = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 1, 22, 52, -20);
var material1 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {color: 0xffff00} );
var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( this.geometry, this.material );

    this.mesh.position.x = x
        this.mesh.position.y = y
        this.mesh.position.z = z

scene.add(this.mesh);

}
   update() {  

        this.mesh.position.z += this.speed;//this.rate;  


         if(this.mesh.position.z > 0.3){        //if torus reaches 0.3 of z axis then return t origional position
            this.mesh.position.z = this.origionalz;
            this.speed += 0.015;                        // speeds up torus each refresh of position



        }

          if ( this.CollidedWithObstacle()){
            console.log("BANG"); 
            //this.sheild --- BANG---  
          }
    }

Move(){

function onDocumentKeyDown(event) {
    var keyCode = event.keyCode;
 if ( keyCode == 87 ) {             //up
        sphere.position.y += 0.5;}  
    else if (keyCode == 83) {       //down
        sphere.position.y -= 0.5; 
    } else if (keyCode == 65) {     //left
        sphere.position.x -= 0.5; 
    } else if (keyCode == 68) {    // right
        sphere.position.x += 0.5; 
    } else if (keyCode == 32) {    //space = return to centre
        sphere.position.x = 0.0;
        sphere.position.y = 0.0;
        sphere.position.z = 0.0;
    }
}

}

 DistanceTo(x,z) {
  let dist = Math.abs ( Math.sqrt(
    (( this.mesh.position.x - x)* (this.mesh.position.x - x ))+ 
    ((this.mesh.position.z - z)* (this.mesh.position.z - z ))));

  return dist;
}

IsCollidedWith(that){
  let collidedWith = (this.size + that.size) > this.DistanceTo(that.mesh.position.x, that.mesh.position);
  return collidedWith;

}

CollidedWithObstacle (){

      for(var n=0; n<obstacle.length; n++){
    if (obstacleList[n].collidable == true){
      if (this.IsCollidedWith(obstacleList[n])==true){
        return true; 
      }
    }
  }
  return false; 
 }

Reset(){

}
 }

var obstacleList4 = [];

var ball = new sphere( 1, 22, 52, -20);
//var ball1 = new sphere( 3, 22, 52, -20);
 obstacleList4.push(ball);







var animate = function () {
         requestAnimationFrame( animate );

        renderer.render(scene, camera);

        for (let i = 0; i < obstacleList.length; i++){
          obstacleList[i].update();
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < obstacleList2.length; i++){
            obstacleList2[i].update();
          }

         for (let i = 0; i < obstacleList3.length; i++){
            obstacleList3[i].update();
        }
        // for (let i = 0; i < obstacleList4.length; i++){
        //     obstacleList4[i].update();
        // }
}

animate();
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO.Please post the TEXT of the error rather than the image. Why are you redeclaring `scene`? What line specifically are lines 300 and 384?

Comment: You have `var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( this.geometry, this.material );` I think you meant `this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh( this.geometry, this.material );`

Comment: Also capitalize `Sphere` class so it won't get mixed up or shadowed by a variable `sphere` in the same scope.

Comment: Thank you, everyone, sadly after these changes have been made there is still no sphere appearing on the scene?

Comment: @IckyArrison To get useful answers on StackOverflow, a Q&A site, you should split up your problem in individual questions *that are actually answerable*. You current problem is your sphere doesn't show up - you either create a new question, or edit this question to reflect this. Change the title to that specific question, include the *current* code (a runnable online version in a codepen or jsfiddle will also help),