# 3D object appears with a black background in my website

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have found a 3d object from three.js that is has a 404 text with a floating orb instead of zero. when I imported its code, it worked but with a black background. I tried to play with the values and tried to add a background color to its container but it didn't work. I also used the inspector but nothing worked. I want to make the background transparent.

(I also tried to make a new website and add it but the same problem appeared)

here is the code

HTML:

```
   <div class="cont-404">
        <p class="mega">4<span class="boom">0</span>4
        <div class="bola"></div>
        </p>
        <p class="mini">That's an error.</p>
     </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r79/three.min.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```
.cont-404{
    float: right;
}
.mini {
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 9em;
    text-indent: 2.5em;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%; 
  }
  .mega, .bola{
    line-height: 1.65em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 11em;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Roboto', saappeared
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%; 
    margin-left: -150px;
    margin-top: -150px;}
   
  .boom {color: #f5f5f5; }
```

JS:

```
var $container = $('.bola');
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(80, 1, 0.1, 10000);
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

scene.add(camera);
renderer.setSize(300, 300);
$container.append(renderer.domElement);

///////////////////////////////////////////////

// Camera
camera.position.z = 200;

// Material
var pinkMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: new THREE.Color("#C3073F"),
    emissive: new THREE.Color("rgb(0,0,0)"),
    specular: new THREE.Color("#C3073F"),
    shininess: 50,
    shading: THREE.FlatShading,
    transparent: 1,
    opacity: 1
});

var L1 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1);
L1.position.z = 100;
L1.position.y = 100;
L1.position.x = 100;
scene.add(L1);

var L2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.8);
L2.position.z = 200;
L2.position.y = 400;
L2.position.x = -100;
scene.add(L2);

// IcoSphere -> THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(80, 1) 1-4
var Ico = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(75, 1), pinkMat);
Ico.rotation.z = 0.5;
scene.add(Ico);

function update() {
    Ico.rotation.x += 2 / 100;
    Ico.rotation.y += 2 / 100;
}

// Render
function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    update();
}

render();
```

[image: An image of the problem]

Comment: You haven't posted your `HTML` code correctly.

Comment: Is it now correct or do you mean that I need to add the <head> and the <body> ?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177056/changing-three-js-background-to-transparent-or-other-color

Comment: `var scene = new THREE.Scene(); // initialising the scene
scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xff0000 );` this code helped

Comment: now i can change the background color but how can I make it transparent ??

Comment: `var scene = new THREE.Scene(); // initialising the scene        scene.background = new THREE.Color( 'transparent' )`

Comment: I tried this but it made the background white

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });

Create the renderer like so:

```js
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true });
```

> var pinkMat = new THREE.MeshPhongaterial({

Typo. It should be `MeshPhongMaterial`.

> color: new THREE.Color("#C3073F")appearedssive: new THREE.Color("rgb(0,0,0)"),

This line does not make sense. Try it with just

```js
color: new THREE.Color("#C3073F"),
```

> var $container = $('.bola');

That's jQuery code which you don't use in your example code.

Here is a fixed live example:

```js
var $container = document.querySelector('.bola')
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true });
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(80, 1, 0.1, 10000);
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

scene.add(camera);
renderer.setSize(300, 300);
$container.append(renderer.domElement);

///////////////////////////////////////////////

// Camera
camera.position.z = 200;

// Material
var pinkMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: new THREE.Color("#C3073F"),
    specular: new THREE.Color("#C3073F"),
    shininess: 50,
    shading: THREE.FlatShading,
    transparent: 1,
    opacity: 1
});

var L1 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1);
L1.position.z = 100;
L1.position.y = 100;
L1.position.x = 100;
scene.add(L1);

var L2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.8);
L2.position.z = 200;
L2.position.y = 400;
L2.position.x = -100;
scene.add(L2);

// IcoSphere -> THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(80, 1) 1-4
var Ico = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(75, 1), pinkMat);
Ico.rotation.z = 0.5;
scene.add(Ico);

function update() {
    Ico.rotation.x += 2 / 100;
    Ico.rotation.y += 2 / 100;
}

// Render
function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    update();
}

render();
```

```css
.cont-404 {
  float: right;
}

.mini {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 9em;
  text-indent: 2.5em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}

.mega,
.bola {
  line-height: 1.65em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 11em;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Roboto', saappeared width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -150px;
  margin-top: -150px;
}

.boom {
  color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont-404">
  <p class="mega">4<span class="boom">0</span>4
    <div class="bola"></div>
  </p>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r79/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: sorry I think something happened that messed my js code I re-copied it and edited the question

Comment: I've updated the code. You have to apply the `alpha` parameter when creating an instance of `WebGLRenderer`.