# How to two Three-JS Objects run and animate at the same time same page?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I can't figure out why by adding a second object the first object stops animating and doesn't run anymore? How can I go about figuring out why my objects are canceling one another out and how to create two different or more multiple threejs items that animate at the same time?
I would like to run more than on three.js script in some file. Someone can help me?
Thank you

```
    //firt object

var scene2 = new THREE.Scene();
document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false );
var camera2 = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 40, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
var mouseX;
var mouseY;

var renderer2 = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer2.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
renderer2.autoClear = false;
document.body.appendChild( renderer2.domElement );

window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
  camera2.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera2.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer2.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
});

var distance = Math.min(200, window.innerWidth / 4);
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

  var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();

  var theta = THREE.Math.randFloatSpread(360); 
  var phi = THREE.Math.randFloatSpread(360); 

  vertex.x = distance * Math.sin(theta) * Math.cos(phi);
  vertex.y = distance * Math.sin(theta) * Math.sin(phi);
  vertex.z = distance * Math.cos(theta);

  geometry.vertices.push(vertex);
}
var particles = new THREE.Points(geometry, new THREE.PointsMaterial({color: 0xFFFF00, size: 2}));
particles.boundingSphere = 50;


var renderingParent = new THREE.Group();
renderingParent.add(particles);

var resizeContainer = new THREE.Group();
resizeContainer.add(renderingParent);
scene2.add(resizeContainer);

camera2.position.z = 400;

var animate = function () {
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
  renderer2.render( scene2, camera2 );
};
var myTween;
function onMouseMove(event) {
  if(myTween)
    myTween.kill();
  
  mouseX = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
  mouseY = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
  myTween = gsap.to(particles.rotation, {duration: 0.1, x: mouseY*-1, y: mouseX});
  //particles.rotation.x = mouseY*-1;
  //particles.rotation.y = mouseX;
}
animate();

// Scaling animation
var animProps = {scale: 0.5, xRot: 0, yRot: 0};
gsap.to(animProps, {duration: 20, scale: 1.5, repeat: -1, yoyo: true, ease: "sine", onUpdate: function() {
  renderingParent.scale.set(animProps.scale,animProps.scale,animProps.scale);
}});

gsap.to(animProps, {duration: 120, xRot: Math.PI * 2, yRot: Math.PI * 4, repeat: -1, yoyo: true, ease: "none", onUpdate: function() {
  renderingParent.rotation.set(animProps.xRot,animProps.yRot,0);
}});
```

'''

```
//second object
<script>
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false );
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 40, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
    var mouseX;
    var mouseY;
    
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    renderer.autoClear = false;
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    
    window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
      camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    });
    
    var distance = Math.min(200, window.innerWidth / 4);
    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    
      var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
    
      var theta = THREE.Math.randFloatSpread(360); 
      var phi = THREE.Math.randFloatSpread(360); 
    
      vertex.x = distance * Math.sin(theta) * Math.cos(phi);
      vertex.y = distance * Math.sin(theta) * Math.sin(phi);
      vertex.z = distance * Math.cos(theta);
    
      geometry.vertices.push(vertex);
    }
    var particles = new THREE.Points(geometry, new THREE.PointsMaterial({color: 0xFFFF00, size: 2}));
    particles.boundingSphere = 50;
    
    
    var renderingParent = new THREE.Group();
    renderingParent.add(particles);
    
    var resizeContainer = new THREE.Group();
    resizeContainer.add(renderingParent);
    scene.add(resizeContainer);
    
    camera.position.z = 400;
    
    var animate = function () {
      requestAnimationFrame( animate );
      renderer.render( scene, camera );
    };
    var myTween;
    function onMouseMove(event) {
      if(myTween)
        myTween.kill();
      
      mouseX = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
      mouseY = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
      myTween = gsap.to(particles.rotation, {duration: 0.1, x: mouseY*-1, y: mouseX});
      //particles.rotation.x = mouseY*-1;
      //particles.rotation.y = mouseX;
    }
    animate();
    
    // Scaling animation
    var animProps = {scale: 0.5, xRot: 0, yRot: 0};
    gsap.to(animProps, {duration: 20, scale: 1.5, repeat: -1, yoyo: true, ease: "sine", onUpdate: function() {
      renderingParent.scale.set(animProps.scale,animProps.scale,animProps.scale);
    }});
    
    gsap.to(animProps, {duration: 120, xRot: Math.PI * 2, yRot: Math.PI * 4, repeat: -1, yoyo: true, ease: "none", onUpdate: function() {
      renderingParent.rotation.set(animProps.xRot,animProps.yRot,0);
    }});
    
    </script>
```

'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two functions named `animate` (even if you've diligently renamed the scene to `scene2`, the camera to `camera2`, etc.)

Since `animate` calls `requestAnimationFrame(animate)`, the other (overwritten) animate function will be called no longer.

The easiest (though by no means pretty) fix is to similarly rename the other animation function to `animate2`.

The better fix would be to refactor this code into functions that have their local namespaces, so mixups like these are harder. (When you do that, you can also refactor the function creating the geometry into a function of its own, etc.)

Comment: Thank a lot AKX first way works, I'll try with second one soon, but thank you a lot. I stuck on another problem, I would like to change background of my scene from black to white but can't find a way to achieve it. Can you help me? Thank you

Comment: I searched for "three.js background color" and found https://stackoverflow.com/a/16177178/51685 – add `scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff );` when you've created a scene.